# RLMArray object not stored with its object

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, realm, rlmarray

I've a very weird problem in RealmSwift.
I've the following property in a realm object class called Device.

```
class Device: Object {
    ....
    dynamic var name: String = ""
    var services: List<Service> = List<Service>()
}
```

The issue is that when trying to fill this list and save the Device object, the service list is not saved.

While debugging I used the following to test

```
print(device)
```

Which prints the objects without any service object.
and

```
print(device.services)
```

Which prints all services objects.
I know it's weird, but I cannot save the object with its list object, although I can save any normal property in the device object like name property.
Any idea what is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing could happen if you are directly assigning to the `services` property. This is not supported, and `List` properties should always be declared as `let`.

Comment: yea, I'm directly assigning to the service property. I think "append" method could work. Will try and check.